# ngx-timepicker-field add clear button

Tags: angular, reset, timepicker

I am using [ngx-material-timepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-timepicker) `ngx-timepicker-field` to create several time pickers.

```
 <ngx-timepicker-field [format]="24"></ngx-timepicker-field>
```

[image]

The time picker are working just fine, but i need to add a clear button to clear/reset the input.

Something similar to the default html timepicker:

[image]

I already searched the docs but couldn't find a way to to it.

How to add such a clear button to the timepicker component?

Let me know if you need additionally information.

Comment: can you please make this app in stackblitz so can give some solution easily if i can

Comment: i will try to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I think having a separate button is completely fine in a user perspective, but if you need to extend the functionality of the lib without forking it's source code, you gotta do some kind of a workaround.

I would try something like this: According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-timepicker) you can change the cancelButton's template ref with the `@Input() cancelBtnTmpl: TemplateRef` to your own implementation: after you switch the default cancel button you can then implement a reset functionality to the time value, as described in my other answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-timepicker), you can manipulate the Value @Input() field and set it's value to null if you want to reset. So something like this might work:

```
 <ngx-timepicker-field [format]="24" #myPickerRef></ngx-timepicker-field>
```

and try to set that `myValue` to null and see what it does:

```
@ViewChild('myPickerRef') NgxTimepicker(or whatever) myTimePicker;
...
myTimePicker.value = 0;
```

(I did not check the code, if you provide a stackblitz example, I can try to create a solution in it)

Comment: Yeah that works. That's how it is currently implemented using an extra button besides the time picker. But i wanted to know if it is possible without adding a button and using something like the `x` in default html time pickers.

Comment: I tried to setup a stackblitz example but run into an error. I will try it again as soon as possible